# Sql Server 2012 Custom/Standard Reports in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I want to develop my own Custom Reports in Sql Server. I would want to know the underlying report logic (tables used, joins etc) of the existing **Standard** reports in SSMS to get an idea. Is it possible to locate the source code (.rdl) of these Standard Reports and get the underlying logic which could be used in my Custom Reports ?

I am using Sql Server 2012

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SSRS can't use .rdl as data source to retrieve data. For your requirement, you should query the system table to retrieve data into a dataset.

Comment: By "system" tables are you referring to the DMV dm_* tables ? Basically I am interested in getting the performance stats of a package executed in the past.

Comment: By "system" tables are you referring to the DMV dm_* tables ? From what I understand the existing Standard Reports show data for current executions. However, I am interested in retrieving _historical_ data for past executions. Do the DMVs store history stats ?